# Firebase promise returns null to the user, but returns normal data in cloud functions testing

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Function keeps returning null on the user-side. Whenever I test the function on Cloud Platform, it returns and displays (through logs) the correct data. I have another function on the server-side, that is literally the same, but it returns everything correctly. Anybody has any clues?

Server-side:

```
exports.getTeam = functions.https.onCall(async function(data, context) {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        let sport = data.sport;
        let year = data.year;
        let teamId = Number(data.id);

        MongoClient.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, async function(err, db) {
            if(err) console.log("Error connecting to DB");
            else
            {
                db.db(sport + year).collection('Teams')
                .find({id: teamId})
                .toArray(function(err, teams) {
                    db.close();
                    resolve(teams[0]); 
                });
            }
        })
    })
});
```

User-side:

```
let getTeam = functions.httpsCallable('getTeam');
await getTeam({"sport":teamSport, "year": teamYear, 'teamId':teamId})
.then(async function(teamInfo) {
    console.log(teamInfo);
    if(teamInfo.data)
    {
        let team = teamInfo.data;
        console.log(team);
    }
    else console.log('Returned null');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Very silly mistake: I was sending teamId with a name teamId, but on the server side I was retrieving id (which was null, due to being sent as teamId from the user side)